# How to reference jscript

Tags: jscript

I feel silly asking this question but I'm dealing with a vendor who told me that in order to generate a specific required key I need to reference the jscript library instead of Javascript.

I know how to reference Javascript but simply changing text/javascript to text/jscript doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe they meant the code has to run under the Windows Scripting Host?

Comment: @MikeChristensen thanks for the response, I think they meant using it in the following way: script language="JScript"> will try that and see if it works.